# ModX, убрать с главной ссылку на главную в пункте меню

Tags: modx, menu

Код чанка выглядит вот так:

```
<div class="top-menu">
                [[pdoMenu? 
                    &parents=`0` 
                    &level=`2`
                    &tpl=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]><span>[[+menutitle]]</span></a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                    &tplParentRow=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><span class="dropdown-button"></span><a style="cursor:default" [[+attributes]]><span>[[+menutitle]]</span></a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                    &where=`{"template:!=":12}`
                ]]
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
```

пожалуйста, подскажите как можно убрать с главной страницы, ссылку на главную в пунтке меню

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте вызов некэшируемым, добавив ! к вызову сниппета и добавьте строку которая будет исключать главную страницу из выборки, при условии, что вызов идет с главной страницы (в примере id главной страницы = 300).

```
<div class="top-menu">
            [[!pdoMenu? 
                [[*id:eq=`300`:then=`&resources=-300`]] 
                &parents=`0` 
                &level=`2`
                &tpl=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]><span>[[+menutitle]]</span></a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                &tplParentRow=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><span class="dropdown-button"></span><a style="cursor:default" [[+attributes]]><span>[[+menutitle]]</span></a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                &where=`{"template:!=":12}`
            ]]
            <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ!!!)))